# Tied score before and after a move. Will the solution post move be accepted?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working a variation of the vehicle routing problem. In my situation, there can be multiple empty vehicles.  If a single trip is in any of them, it will have the same score.  If a move places the trip into one of these empty vehicles how do I control whether Optaplanner will accept this new move, whether it will randomly choose, or whether it will reject this new solution?

Answer (score 0):

Most LocalSearch types will accept it. SA and LA will probably accept it immediatly due to acceptedLimitCount 1, but TS will typically evaluate more moves but might still end up picking it if it's the best accepted move.

See Accepter interface.